# SetWindowDisplayAffinity does not work for console app

Tags: winapi, windows-console, win32-process

I get accessdenied(5) error in following console app codes, is there anyway to protect console window against screenshot?

```
int wmain(void)
{
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    BOOL b = SetWindowDisplayAffinity(hWnd, WDA_MONITOR);
    DWORD e = GetLastError();   // e==5
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity):

> **Parameters**
>
> **hWnd**
>
> Type: **HWND**
>
> A handle to the top-level window. The window must belong to the
> current process.

The console does not belong to the current process, so the HWND cannot be set.